# How to set the value of hyperlink in a PHP Variable?

Tags: php

Today I wanna ask you  about a trick that I wanna do, I wanna set a value of an hyperlink in a variable.
For eg:
I have the following code:`<a href="#">Text/a>`

what I need is to put the "Text" in a PHP Variable.??

I need an explained Example if you can..

Can you Help me?

Comment: I mean: <a href="#"> Text </a>

Comment: I understand this being tagged duplicate, but the linked question does not answer his query.